# How to work in-cell editing in Autohotkey listview

Tags: listview, autohotkey

In my GUI, I have a standard listview control into which I've loaded several rows worth of values.

How can I fix it so when I click on the field in the listview that it enters text-edit mode for that cell?

I know how to bring up an separate edit box, but that's not what I want to do.  I want to edit the text in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documents](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ListView.htm#bifRow):

*ReadOnly: Specify -ReadOnly (minus ReadOnly) to allow editing of the text in the first column of each row. To edit a row, select it then press the F2 key. Alternatively, you can click a row once to select it, wait at least half a second, then click the same row again to edit it.*

Comment: @BGM It took me literally 14 seconds to find the answer. And i copy pasted your question into google. Just sayin...

Comment: I guess I wasn't as lucky as you.  Sometimes you can't see something, sometimes you can.  If I could have found it, I wouldn't have asked the question here.  I even searched the ahk forum.

Comment: Thanks, then.  If you and I remove these silly comments, I'll mark you solved and give you a +1 for having the sympathy to help me.

Comment: that works for the row, but something is the matter - I can't edit the cells in the other columns.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Okay, you CAN'T edit cells in the other columns by default.  But the script here will let you do it: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/77590-class-lv-incelledit-in-cell-editing-for-listviews/

Comment: @BGM Congratulations, you made a first step towards success.